# Integral inequality similar to Hardy's

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

I am trying to solve following puzzle:

We are given functions $f$, where $f(x) > 0$ and $F := \int_0^x f(t) dt$ and some real $p>1$.

Does $\int_0^\infty f(x)^p e^{-x}dx < \infty$ imply $\int_0^\infty F(x)^pe^{-x}dx < \infty$ ?

This inequality looks a bit similiar to Hardy's, but now I begin thinking that it is too strong and just not true. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $f(x)\ge 0$?

Comment: Ah yes, it is. Thank you. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Have you tried taking $f(x)$ as $e^{x/p}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{E}(x)$ and suitably choosing the set $E$?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll check.

Comment: Jack, I think this is not the right direction to go, as far as I understand. if we choose $f(x) = e^{x/p} \cdot \mathbb{1}_E (x)$, then $F(x) = p  e^{x/p} \mathbb{1}_E (x)$, and $\int_0^\infty F(x) dx = p^p \int_0^\infty f(x)$, which is in accord with statement of the task (does not offer counterexample to the question).

Answer (score 0):

Either I have solved it or I am stupid. Second is very possible. Please verify.

First, let us notice that by Jensen we obtain 
$$
\left(\int_0^\infty f(t) dt \right)^p \leq \int_0^\infty f(t)^p dt
$$

Now let us write
$$
\int_0^\infty F(x)^p e^{-x} dx = \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^x f(t) dt \right)^p e^{-x} dx \leq \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \left(\int_0^x f(t)^p dt \right)  dx,
$$

where the last inequality is application of above stated Jensen's.

Now, by Fubini's we may write
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \left(\int_0^x f(t)^p dt \right)  dx = \int_0^\infty f(t)^p \left(\int_t^\infty e^{-x} dx \right) dt = \int_0^\infty f(t)^p e^{-t} dt,
$$

where the last equality is obtained by integrating $\int_t^\infty e^{-x} = e^{-t}$.

Help with verifying or disproving above is again, appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Doesn't Jensen only hold for sets with measure $1$ ? It is the case of $\mathbb{R}_+$ for the measure $\mathrm{e}^{-x}\mathrm{d}x$, but not for the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: You are right! Thanks. Will try fixing.